# Is it possible to repeat a /begin{something} n times?

Tags: packages, environments

I want to define an environment that is inside n fill environments. But when I try to complile the code, i get

```
    "message": "Illegal parameter number in definition of \\endsubproof.\n<to be read again> \n",
```

here is the code

```latex
\newcommand{\Repeat}[2]{% \repeat already defined
    \foreach \n in {1,...,#1}{#2}
}

\newenvironment{subproof}[2][1]{
  %begin
  \Repeat{\number#1}{\begin{subproofill}}
  \begin{tcolorbox}[demo, title = #2, colframe = black]
  \vspace*{5\logicv}
}{
  %end
  \end{tcolorbox}
  \Repeat{\number#1}{\end{subproofill}}
}
```

Using a command to store #1 worked for the error shown above. But now there is a problem compiling the environment using `/Repeat{n}{\begin{som}}`
example code:

```latex
    \Repeat{2}{\begin{subproofill}}
        hola
    \Repeat{2}{\end{subproofill}}
```

This is throwing several errors  (none if i dont use \Repeat)

Comment: the argument of the environment is not available in the end code, save `#1` in the begin code to a local command to use at the end

Comment: it worked, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument of the environment is not available in the end code, save `#1` in the begin code to a local command to use at the end